# Sphinx-apidocs not generating TODO documentation from python code

Tags: python-sphinx

I have setup Sphinx api docs which generating html documentation from my python code. So only missing thing is that it is not generating # TODO documentation.

I have check on different web sites and Sphinx api-doc documentation and checked my configuration, it looks fine.

Here is my configuration:

config.py

```
extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
'sphinx.ext.todo',
'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
]

todo_include_todos = True
```

And while setting up quickstart,

> todo: write "todo" entries that can be shown or hidden on build (y/n) [n]: y

And documentation in .py file

```
def post(self):
    """
    Adds a :class:`Persona` resource in Persona resource list.

    :returns: A newly created Persona resource with http 201 response code.
    """
    args = parser.parse_args()
    persona_id = int(max(PERSONAS.keys())) + 1
    persona_id = '%i' % persona_id
    PERSONAS[persona_id] = {'name': args['name']}

    # TODO Validate all post fields

    return PERSONAS[persona_id], 201
```

Above code docs generated but # TODO part not in generated docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sphinx does not do anything with `# TODO` comments.

What Sphinx can do is to process todo items specified with the special [`todo`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/todo.html) directive. It can be included in the docstring:

```py
def post(self):
    """
    Adds a :class:`Persona` resource in Persona resource list.

    :returns: A newly created Persona resource with http 201 response code.

    .. todo::

       Validate all post fields 

    """
```